# Google Spreadsheets: Log content of cell into new sheet on every change

Tags: logging, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have this Ranking chart
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AveLEDuTZv0vdFNua09BRjBTUm1Renh5U0NOTlZRTlE&usp=drive_web#gid=0

Where I would want to "Log" *every Change* of Cell **D1** into a new sheet called Log. Latest Changes should be on top. (like shown in the example) Is this doable in google spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its doable. You can either monitor changes using onEdit/onChange triggers or you can do a minute-trigger to check if it changed. First option is best.

Comment: Yeah, I already thought to trigger the function by onEdit. But I would need some help in writing that function... Basically, to copy cell content to another sheet, but always inserting an empty line at the beginning, so new entries are on top.

Comment: take a look at insertRow. however I recommend that you invert the order of your list so newer items are at the bottom (using appendRow instead) because its more efficient.